# Increase Flutter Radio Widget size

Tags: flutter, frontend

I am using default Flutter Radio Widget. I want to increase its size but there is no property available for it.

Tried using SizedBox with width: 50, height: 50. Didn't help.

Not want to implement a whole custom radio button. Just want to increase the default's size.
Thanks

Answer (score 34):

Well you can wrap it in Transform.Scale then use the scale property to increase it.

```
Transform.scale(
       scale: 2.0,
       child: Radio(
       value: 'wire',
       groupValue: selectedRadio,
       onChanged: (value)=>radioSelected(value),
       activeColor: Color(0xffFFBD11),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without creating your own Widget.

You should have a look at [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_radio).

Comment: Exactly...There is not any way to increase the height and width of the radio button

Comment: @AR well you can use Transform.scale as a work around

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transform.scale widget for this.

```
Transform.scale(
   scale: 3.0,
   child: 
 Radio(
   value: 10,
   groupValue: yourValue,
   onChanged: (value){radioSelected(yourVar=value)},
  ),
),
```